# Lua in pairs with same order as it's written

Tags: loops, lua, lua-table

Is there any way to loop trough a table like the one below in the same order as it's written?

```
local tbl = {
    ["hello"] = 1,
    [2] = 2,
    [50] = 3,
    ["bye"] = 4,
    [200] = 5
}
```

What I mean is that when I use "in pairs" I'll get a different order everytime I execute my code ...

I'm searching for something like this:

```
function get_keys(tbl)
    local rtable = {}
    for k,v in pairs(tbl) do
        table.insert(rtable, k)
    end
    return rtable
end

local keys_of_tbl = get_keys(tbl)
for i = 1, table.getn(keys_of_tbl) do
    --Do something with: tbl[keys_of_tbl[i]]
end
```

But because the function "get_keys" is based on "in pairs" again, it won't work ...

Comment: Are those values the order you want to loop in? Or is that just a coincidence here?

Comment: I want to loop trough the table "tbl" in the same order as it's written, so first gotrough should be key "hello", second 2, third 50, ...

Comment: Depending on in-source order is asking for problems later when someone who doesn't realize that order matters re-arranges things for some reason. If you need an explicit order make the order explicit.

Comment: I added another working solution for my problem :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Lua, the order that pairs iterates through the keys is unspecified. However you can save the order in which items are added in an array-style table and use `ipairs` (which has a defined order for iterating keys in an array). To help with that you can create your own ordered table using metatables so that the key order will be maintained when new keys are added.

---

**EDIT** (earlier code inserted multiple copies of the key on updates)

To do this you can use `__newindex` which we be called so long as the index is not added yet to the table. The `ordered_add` method updates, deletes, or stores the key in the hidden tables `_keys` and `_values`. Note that `__newindex` will always be called when we update the key too since we didn't store the value in the table but instead stored it in the "hidden" tables `_keys` and `_values`.

Note however that we cannot use any key in this table, the key name `"_keys"` will overwrite our hidden table so the safer alternative is to use the `ordered_table.insert(t, key, value)` `ordered_table.index(t, key)` and `ordered_table.remove(t, key)` methods.

```
ordered_table = {}

function ordered_table.insert(t, k, v)
  if not rawget(t._values, k) then -- new key 
    t._keys[#t._keys + 1] = k
  end
  if v == nil then -- delete key too.
    ordered_table.remove(t, k)
  else -- update/store value
    t._values[k] = v 
  end
end

local function find(t, value)
  for i,v in ipairs(t) do
    if v == value then
      return i
    end
  end
end  

function ordered_table.remove(t, k)
  local v = t._values[k]
  if v ~= nil then
    table.remove(t._keys, find(t._keys, k))
    t._values[k] = nil
  end
  return v
end

function ordered_table.index(t, k)
    return rawget(t._values, k)
end

function ordered_table.pairs(t)
  local i = 0
  return function()
    i = i + 1
    local key = t._keys[i]
    if key ~= nil then
      return key, t._values[key]
    end
  end
end

function ordered_table.new(init)
  init = init or {}
  local t = {_keys={}, _values={}}
  local n = #init
  if n % 2 ~= 0 then
    error"in ordered_table initialization: key is missing value"
  end
  for i=1,n/2 do
    local k = init[i * 2 - 1]
    local v = init[i * 2]
    if t._values[k] ~= nil then
      error("duplicate key:"..k)
    end
    t._keys[#t._keys + 1]  = k
    t._values[k] = v
  end
  return setmetatable(t,
    {__newindex=ordered_table.insert,
    __len=function(t) return #t._keys end,
    __pairs=ordered_table.pairs,
    __index=t._values
    })
end

--- Example Usage:
local t = ordered_table.new{
  "hello", 1,  -- key, value pairs
  2, 2,
  50, 3,
  "bye", 4,
  200, 5
}

print(#t)
print("hello is", t.hello)
print()
for k, v in pairs(t) do  --- Lua 5.2 __pairs metamethod
  print(k, v)
end
t.bye = nil -- delete that
t[2] = 7 -- use integer keys
print(#t)
```

Comment: As a rule, no one can be responsible for all the possible incorrect extrapolations one might make from their code; there are simply too many wrong ways to do something. I have abstracted out the search and now the remove is clearly not within a loop, I hope this satisfies us both :)

Comment: That works for me. =) Thank you. Were this code I was seeing on github/etc. I wouldn't have commented on it (or thought much about it at all). But specifically in the context of SO and the long-tail intention of the help provided by the site and its target audience I think solutions should be less "encumbered" whenever possible.

Answer (score 5):

No. There's no "as written in the source" order to tables. (Consider that not all keys necessarily exist in the source.) lua has no concept of "in order" for non-contiguous integer keys.

If you want a specific order you get to keep that order yourself manually in some way.

If you don't have any integer keys in your table then you can use those as your order (and use `ipairs` to loop those keys and index the value as the key to get the real value).

If your original values are the order you want to sort in then you can loop and reverse map to get a table that you can iterate with `ipairs` once done.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go that way ... not as nice as it would be but if it's not possible this will be the single way x.x