# Reading lua into c# onbject

Tags: c#, lua

I know its possible to pass Json data into c# object, but is it possible to do with lua?

Lets say this is my lua code:

```
data:extend(
{
  {
    type = "technology",
    localised_name = {"technology-name.logistic-science-pack"},
    effects =
    {
      {
        type = "unlock-recipe",
        recipe = "logistic-science-pack"
      }
    },
    unit =
    {
      count = 75,
      ingredients = {{"automation-science-pack", 1}},
      time = 5
    },
  },
  {
    type = "technology",
    localised_name = {"technology-name.chemical-science-pack"},
    effects =
    {
      {
        type = "unlock-recipe",
        recipe = "chemical-science-pack"
      }
    },
    unit =
    {
      count = 75,
      ingredients =
      {
        {"automation-science-pack", 1},
        {"logistic-science-pack", 1}
      },
      time = 10
    },
    prerequisites = {"advanced-electronics", "sulfur-processing"},
  },
}
)
```

Yes, its a list of same object.
This code, alto shortened, is from a game that I took as an example (and what 'm using to play around with lua).

Would it be possible to convert this lua code/data into a c# object or at least into Json so later you can convert Json into c# object?

I been trying to find the answer on the net, but all I'm finding is how to use lua for scrips or writing a script to create and store c# objects. Nothing what im looking for.

**Also** what nuGet package should I get or would you recommend? It seems there a lot of em on nuGet package browser (VS) and over the net there are a lot of different opinions.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: p.s. i dont know lua. all i know is that u can write scripts with it. so it might be impossible what im asking, but want to make sure it is. or maybe there is a work around? anything helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use lua C# engine (like Nlua), you can get object direcly from this engine. If you name lua state as `state` it may be returned by `state.DoString ("return data")[0]`.

If you connect only to C#, you have to use serializing. JSON is good documented and mature format and have many lua libraries. My personal best is [dkjson](http://dkolf.de/src/dkjson-lua.fsl/home).

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response! Took me an hour to even manage to print out the values and keys from a lua file, that a limit and table number is unknown, to console :D
managed to get done what i wished, all thanks to you!
Alto i do not like being "spoon fed" but is there a quicker way to get the data to an object? currently i read each table and pass it by object.variable = table.value (shortened version) for each variable. The more variables the bigger the code :(

Comment: O also, is there away to make force read the same order it was written? Each time i re-compile, the read order changes.

Comment: Reading objects using pairs, and there is some [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30970034/lua-in-pairs-with-same-order-as-its-written).