# Does `next()` yield in some stable order if only field values are modified?

Tags: lua, iteration, lua-table

I am generating a string to represent a state encoded in a table.  The state will change by changing the values of some table entries.  I will never (after calling `mkName()` below) add or remove keys to/from the table.

I want the string to be a kind of "canonical name" of the state in the table so if I change values in the table and then change them back I want that "name" to be the same again.  Currently I am using `pairs()` directly on my table to read all the values from it.  Is that traversal order stable across value changes?

My code looks like this

```lua
local function mkName(t)
  local name = ""
  for k, v in pairs(t) do name = name .. k .. ":" .. v .. "," end
  return name
end
local state = { a=1, b=2, c=3 }
local name1 = mkName(state)
state.b = 10
local name2 = mkName(state)
state.b = 2
local name3 = mkName(state)
-- Here I want name1 and name3 to be equal
print(name1, name2, name3, name1==name3)
```

This works and is stable in the sense that I want but the official docs for `next()` (used by `pairs()`) say:

> The order in which the indices are enumerated is not specified, even for numeric indices. (To traverse a table in numeric order, use a numerical for or the ipairs function.)

Is there any reason why the order of iteration might change for a subsequent call to `pairs()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lua in pairs with same order as it's written](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30970034/lua-in-pairs-with-same-order-as-its-written)

Comment: If there is a hash collision between key1 and key2, then the order of traversing them by `pairs` depends on the order of assignment to these keys.

Comment: You should manually sort the keys alphabetically prior to building the concatenation.

Comment: @PatrickBeynio after a second thought that kind of answers it: ["In Lua, the order that pairs iterates through the keys is unspecified."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30970276/4102092) can be understood as "the order *might* not be stable" although they do not give any reference.

Comment: @Lucas as stated in the official docs [here](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-pairs) `pairs` uses `next` and from [here](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-next) about `next`: _The order in which the indices are enumerated is not specified, even for numeric indices._

Comment: @PatrickBeynio I don't understand what new info you add in your last comment. It just quotes the same thing I  already quoted in my original question. But our discussion in these comments best sums up what I now consider the "solution" so if you want to turn it into  an answer I will accept  it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you do not rely on what is not promised but could accidentally work, but guarantee a stable traversal order for your state function. It can be done like this:

```lua
-- Iterator to replace pairs():
local function ordered_pairs (t)
    -- Get table keys:
    local keys = {}
    for key, _ in pairs (t) do
        table.insert (keys, key)
    end
    -- Sort them:
    table.sort (keys, function (a, b)
        local type_a, type_b = type (a), type (b)
        return type_a < type_b
            or type_a == type_b and (type_a == 'number' or type_a == 'string') and a < b
            or type_a == type_b and tostring (a) < tostring (b)
    end)
    -- Loop over the sorted keys:
    local counter = 1
    return function()
        local key = keys [counter]
        if key then
            counter = counter + 1
            return key, t [key]
        end
    end
end
            
-- Actually, it's a serialiser:
local function hash (t)
    local serialised = {}
    for key, value in ordered_pairs (t) do
        table.insert (serialised, tostring (key) .. ':' .. tostring (value))
    end
    return table.concat (serialised, ',')
end

-- Test:
local t = {a = 1, b = 2, c = 3}
print ('Stage 1 (b = 2):', hash (t))
t.b = 10
print ('Stage 2 (b = 10):', hash (t))
t.b = 2
print ('Stage 3 (b = 2):', hash (t))
```

The keys are ordered first (the sorting function is rather complex to take all possible key types into account). Then the table is iterated in the order of its keys.

If you want, you can override `pairs` for the table with `ordered_pairs`, using its metatable and `__pairs`.